# How to delete all user roles in Kohana 3

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-auth

I'm using ORM Auth module and it's difficult to figure out how to do it. I've tried this case:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user', $id);
$user->roles->delete_all();
```

And got error `ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined method Database_Query_Builder_Delete::join()`

However `$user->roles->find_all();` gives me exactly what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting roles from the database, what you want to do is remove the relationships between the user model and the roles model.  You can use the [ORM remove() method](http://kohanaframework.org/guide/api/ORM#remove).

```
foreach ($user->roles->find_all() as $role)
{
    $user->remove('roles', $role);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly :) Still, i could not resist to delete roles without ORM DB::delete('roles_users')->where('user_id','=',$id)->execute();

Answer (score 7):

According to version 3.1.3.1 code for Kohana_ORM class, the ORM method "remove($alias, $far_keys=NULL)" if you do not pass the second parameter, it will destroy all related entries.

```
$user->remove('roles');
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a [ticket](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3202) for this feature. You can use a code suggested.